# Breeze cannot handle Complex Type Array (Non-Scalar) property from remote service

Tags: arrays, odata, breeze, complextype, scalar

- Library: BreezeJS 1.4.11 client-side library
- Data Service Adapter: webApiOdata
- Remote Service: Web API 2 Implementation of OData v3 **without** Breeze Controller
- Database: MongoDb

I'm running into an issue when handling metadata exposed from an OData service. Here's an example property:

```
<Property Name="Customers" Type="Collection(My.Namespace.Customer)" ConcurrencyMode="Fixed" DefaultValue="" Nullable="false"/>
```

Metadata appears to import successfully from the service endpoint; however, upon closer investigation the parseTypeName() function in Breeze is incorrectly assigning the shortName to "Customer)" and the complexTypeName to "Customer):#My.Namespace".

When trying to run a query, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method '_createInstanceCore' of null

When debugging this error, I notice that the property's dataType = null and isScalar = true.

I cannot use hand-crafting metadata on the client as a workaround, since the metadata can frequently change. I need to be able to import the metadata from the remote service.

Comment: I've run into that too. Stay tuned.